# How to build mobile website with ionic 1.2

Tags: ionic-framework

How does one build a mobile website with ionic 1.2? I can't find any official guides/tutorials/docs.

This is an excerpt from a post on the ionic blog announcing [ionic 1.2 release](http://blog.ionic.io/announcing-ionic-1-2/):

Ionic 1.2 marks the first release where we actively recommend Ionic for those looking to build a mobile website (not just an app for the app store)

Answer (score 0):

Well, there's nothing stopping you from deploying it as a web app, as long as you don't have cordova dependencies in your app (for the natives). Also be aware that non webkit based browsers will probably malfunction.

Look at [this thread](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/deploy-ionic-app-as-a-website/2845/3) for testimonials with mixed results